# inserting multiple checkboxes names with codeigniter in to mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make a timetable with, Codeigniter
but I have a problem with looping.

My view

Class

```
`<input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="1A" id="1a" /> 1A 
<input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="1B" id="1b" /> 1B 
<input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="1C" id="1c" /> 1C `
```

Hours

`<input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" value="1" id="h1" /> hours 1
     <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" value="2" id="h2" /> hours 2 
    <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" value="3" id="h3" /> hours 3
    <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" value="4" id="h4" /> hours 4 
    <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" value="5" id="h5" /> hours 5 
    <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" value="6" id="h6" /> hours 6`

Day

```
`<input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="1" id="Monday" /> Monday
<input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="2" id="Tuesday" /> Tuesday 
<input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="3" id="Wednesday" /> Wednesday
<input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="4" id="Thursday" /> Thursday 
<input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="5" id="Friday" /> Friday 
<input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="6" id="Saturday" /> Saturday `
```

room

` A

```
<input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="B" id="b" /> B 
<input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="C" id="c" /> C 
<input type="checkbox" name="room[]" value="C" id="d" /> D `
```

my model

function add(){

```
    $day= $this->input->post('day');
    $hours= $this->input->post('hours');
    $class= $this->input->post('class');
    $room= $this->input->post('room');


    foreach ($hoursas $hr){
    $data = array('day'=>$day,'hours'=>$hr,'class'=>$class,'room'=>$room);
    $this->db->insert('t_jadual', $data);
    }
}
```

how do I loop $class,$room and $day?

Comment: Can you write example of end result ?

Comment: You would loop through them the same way you would any other loop.
Also, your $this->db->insert() call isn't going to do much. It doesn't actually query the DB: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert